# Safari & event.target.select()

Tags: reactjs, safari

My Safari (11.1.2) deselects a selected text immitiatly. Is this a known bug? Chrome and Firefox keep the selection

I wrote a small example as react component:

```
const Foobar = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value="foobar" onFocus={e => e.target.select()} />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Foobar />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zLjqbZ

Answer (score 0):

Add the line:

```
onMouseUp={e=>e.preventDefault()}
```